# How can I obtain screen scaling similar to Slither.io's using Phaser.js?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am writing a small game in Javascript using the Phaser.js engine as a backend. However, knowing it is possible, the screen scaling issue has proven to be one
of the hardest sides of this.

Slither.io expands to fill the entire screen, and keeps the ratio. I want to use that as my own scaling method as well, but examples seem to be rather sparse. 
The ones I have come across have not been all that clear.

These two functions are what I have come up with thus far, but they seem to cause the sprites to match the window scale - not keep a ratio and scale.

```
function resizeWindow()
{
    game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
    game.width = window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
    game.height = window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatioz;    

    gameScale = game.width / game.height;

if (game.height > game.width){
    gameScale = (game.height / 300);
} else {
    gameScale = (game.width / 480);
}   

    //game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
    game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;    
    game.scale.refresh();   
    gameScaleManager();
}

function gameScaleManager()
{

    for(var i = 0; i < spriteList.length; i++)
    {
        spriteList[i].scale.setTo(gameScale, gameScale);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://phaser.io/examples/v2/display/fullscreen https://phaser.io/examples/v2/display/fullscreen-buttons

Comment: Unless you provide your own images for different screen scales I don't think you can keep the scale of your current images.

Comment: But check the docs for Scale manager, i think there were 4 options for scaling, SHOW_ALL, EXACT_FIT, RESIZE and NO_SCALE I think.

Comment: Considering you can manipulate the scale of groups and objects, it ought to be possible. I'm mainly looking to fit the ratio of the screen.

Comment: Try with the constants I mentioned previosly. But to fit different screen sizes you should load different spritesheets that will be used by the game code. You can change the graphics being loaded programatically. But also your game should be smart enough how to handle different visual objects when the screen size changes.

Comment: I would say not a simple task. You should try your game in different screen sizes and learn from it, which elements should scale and how much. There is no silver bullet. Different games would require different settings :)

Comment: Strangely enough, I have said resizing to fit ratio working now... but I'm not sure why. Two projects, almost the same code... one it works, the second it tends to try to fit the actual ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by way of a number of things

First, set your game scale mode to:

```
game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.RESIZE;
and then apply
game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
```

This does matter, especially for full window size.
Instead of relying on jQuery for rescaling, I then set this:

```
game.scale.setResizeCallback(rescale);
```

The rescale method handles screen scaling.

Finally, this method takes care of the actual work along with the "RESIZE" scale mode, which WILL affect -how- it works. EXACT_FIT and others tend to force the resolution to be the same as the window, from the experimentation I've done.

```
function rescale()
{
    var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;    

    baseWidth = windowWidth * (gameHeight / windowHeight);
    baseHeight = gameHeight;

    if (windowHeight > windowWidth)
    {
        systemScale = (windowHeight / baseHeight) / 1.8;
    } else {
        systemScale = (windowWidth / baseWidth) / 1.8;
    }

    skyBackgroundGroup.scale.setTo(systemScale * (window.innerWidth - DPR / window.innerWidth - DPR) / 100 * 1, systemScale * 2.1);
    MasterControlGroup.scale.setTo(systemScale / 0.98, systemScale / 0.98);
}
```

The divide by scale of 1.8 and 0.98 are entirely personal preferences. 
I almost forgot the biggest part of it - have your camera focus on the center object you are watching.